# Simplest way of overwriting an accessors getter method?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2

Consider the following code:

```
// MyClass.h
@interface MyClass
    @property NSInteger Value;
@end

//MyClass.m
@implementation MyClass
    @synthesize Value;
@end
```

What are the minimal code modifications that I'd need to make if I wanted to override **only** the synthesized setter method for `Value`?

As a follow-up, what are the minimal modifications that I'd have to make in order to override **only** the synthesized getter method?

**EDIT**

Overriding is simple. (See answers below.)  In my case, I was getting a nasty warning because I hadn't included the `nonatomic` attribute with my property definitions.  Adding the attribute has solved my initial problem resulting in this question.

Comment: Pay attention that changing from "atomic" to "nonatomic" is not a mere syntactic change - the property behavior will change, and you may experience crashes if your code attempts to access this property from multiple dispatch_queue's or NSOperationQueues or threads, or even a concurrent version of any  'enumerate:' Cocoa method on any collection. Beware of this change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently it's not possible to override just one or the other for an atomic property. You must change it to have the `nonatomic` attribute.

```
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger value;
```

I didn't know that five minutes ago, and it's not noted anywhere in [TOCPL](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html) as far as I can see.

<sub>Also change the name to be lower-case. Convention in ObjC is for lower initial letters for ivars.</sub>

Beyond that, just implement whichever you want, and the compiler will do the rest. You can validly override none, one, or both.

Just the getter:

```
@implementation MyClass

@synthesize value;

- (NSInteger) value {
    return value;
}

@end
```

Just the setter:

```
@implementation MyClass

@synthesize value;

- (void) setValue: (NSInteger)newValue {
    value = newValue;
}

@end
```

The methods for object types (and covering atomicity) are only slightly more complicated; there are several question here on SO, and [some info in the Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/AddingBehaviortoaCocoaProgram/AddingBehaviorCocoa.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH5-SW5) that will explain.

Comment: Can I get a modified sample of the one above.  Specifically, I tried to override a setter and I'm getting a `Writable atomic property 'Value' cannot pair a synthesized setter/getter with a user defined setter/getter` error message in my code.

Comment: Thank you.  FYI, in the case of my error, adding the `(nonatomic)` attribute to my properties fixed the warning.

Comment: That's interesting. Looks like maybe you also have to make it `nonatomic`. I just learned something!

Comment: I guess this could make since.  Long time programmer, but I'm very new to obj-c.  I guess the compiler throws a warning because synthesized "atomic" properties must have special code in place to keep everything safe across threads.  I've yet to need multi-threading in my application, so if I ever do, I'll dig deeper and cross that bridge when I come to it.

Comment: Yes, it's strange that they made atomic the default; it is so infrequently necessary.

Comment: atomic is the default for good reason - that most programmers are not aware of multi-threaded accessor-implementation complexities, and now Cocoa is multithreaded everywhere - with queues and code-blocks and fast enumeration etc. Next - since atomic property accessors must match locking/unlocking in their getter and setter - you must implement BOTH if you want to override. Otherwise - by definition, your 'getter' or 'setter' won't match the synthesized other - and atomicity will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

Leave everything above as is (other than changing `Value` to `value` to standardize), and then you can implement either one or both of:

```
-(NSInteger)value
{
    return value;
}

-(void)setValue:(NSInteger)newValue
{
    value = newValue;
}
```

`value` is automatically created as a class field.  If you are working with a retained object, you will need to manually retain/release unless you are using ARC.